# Move user to a different role based on X time on server

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I've been messing around with this for quite a while and I don't seem to get it to work.
I want my Discord bot to auto-assign a different role when a user gets the 'Novitiate' role. This is because I want to give new recruits to our in-game guild a one week test period before they become a full 'Member'.
How can I automate this using a Discord bot?

So far I've been trying things like this, but all to no avail:

```
bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.member.roles.has(role => role.name === 'Novitiate')) {
       // user has that role
       message.member.addRole('Member');
       console.log(`User has been moved to new role!`);
    }
});
```

I have no idea how to set a 'timer' when user has given a specific role (Novitiate) so I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Check periodically on all users of the guild with `setInterval` (every 10s, 30s, 1 minute, or even more depending on how time-sensitive it is).
If member has role "Novitiate", check [`member.joinedAt`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=joinedAt). If now is at least 7 days more than member.joinedAt, add the `Member` role and remove the `Novitiate` one.

Comment: Also, `array.has()` isn't a JavaScript built-in function (see on line 2 - `message.member.roles.has(..)`). Use [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) instead.

Comment: @ItaiSteinherz [`roles`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=roles) is a `collection`, which is an object extending Map. And `map.has()` is a perfectly valid function ;)

Comment: @MadWard I didn't assume that since you passed a function to `.has`. If `roles` is a `Map`, then the condition should be `message.member.roles.array().some(role => role.name === 'Novitiate')`.

Comment: @ItaiSteinherz, you're right. `message.member.roles.has` doesn't work properly for checking a role on a user. Your suggestion: `message.member.roles.array().some(role => role.name === 'Novitiate')` does though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Discord.js has an Event which you can listen to called [`guildMemberUpdate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberUpdate) which gets fired whenever a guildmember gets... well... updated. Among more, this includes adding/removing roles. This means you can listen for member updates and determine whether or not a user has gotten a new role and if that new role is 'Novitiate'.

After that you need to save the timestamp/date in a file or some database and periodically check that. If it has been more than 7 days since a user got the role, assign that user a new role.

Some example code (not tested but should give an idea):

```js
bot.on('guildMemberUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
    if (!(oldMember.roles.has(role => role.name === 'Novitiate')) &&
        newMember.roles.has(role => role.name === 'Novitiate')) {
       // member has gotten the role 'Novitiate'

       // This doesn't work, it just a demo on saving the timestamp
       database.save('assignedRole', { user: newMember.id, guild: newMember.guild, date: new Date() });
    }
});

function periodicalCheck () {
    let rows = database.get('assignedRole');
    let alteredRows = rows;

    for (let row of rows) {
        if (dateDiff(row.date) >= 7) {
            let guild = bot.guilds.find(guild => guild.id === row.guild);
            let member = guild.members.find(member => member.id === row.user);
            member.addRole('Member');
            alteredRows.splice(alteredRows.indexOf(row), 1);
        }
    }

    // Remove the records which have been used to clean up the database
    database.set('assignedRole', alteredRows);
}

function dateDiff (date) {
    let timeDiff = Math.abs(new Date().getTime() - new Date(date).getTime());
    return Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
}
```

The only thing to do now is find a way of storing that information and calling the `periodicalCheck` method with an interval.

Comment: Oof! Didn't expect it to be so difficult as I just know some basic JS. This is beyond my scope for me as I don't understand much of your example (the periodicalCheck function that is). Thank you anyway!

Comment: Which parts about it do you not understand? I might be able to explain them better

Comment: How do I save this in a file? Also:
`alteredRows.splice(alteredRows.indexOf(row), 1);`
What does this do?

`return Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));`
And what is being calculated here? 3600 seconds = 1 hour, * 24 = day, 1000 = ??

Comment: @nerdrocker I'm not quite sure with what you mean by 'How do I save this in a file?'... For the other questions, here you can read up about [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). For the `Math.ceil` part, `new Date().getTime()` returns a value in milliseconds, not in seconds. Therefor to calculate how many days have passed, you divide the time by the amount of milliseconds in a day. The `Math.ceil` just rounds the value up to a whole number

Comment: Thank you!
Well, you said: "After that you need to save the timestamp/date in a file or some database and periodically check that." - My question is: how do you do that? I don't have any experience with this. That's why I said this beyond my scope. I appreciate your help a lot btw!

Comment: Ah like so, well you can EITHER save the data in an online database OR save it in a local (JSON) file which your bot can read and write to. [Some information about reading and writing files](https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-files-with-node-js/)

Comment: I will check it out and come back here again when I manage to get it all working. Thanks again!